# Using read.csv() to interpret non numeric values as NA

Tags: r

I am reading a large `.csv` file with the following code

```
read.csv(my_data.csv, colClasses = c("integer", "Date", "numeric"))
```

The problem is that though the third column is numeric but may contains any character as NA value. So I cannot specify all of them in the `na.strings` argument.

Comment: Read the third column as characters at first, and then use `as.numeric()` to convert it. All non-numeric words will become NAs.

Comment: I wanted to suggest the same as @DarrenTsai. Just make sure to use the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` argument with `read.csv`, otherwise there are going to be some nasty surprises ;)